# Exceptions on search, register and install on PyPI hosted repos

Tags: python, nexus, nexus3

Nexus OSS 3.7.1-02 running on RHEL7, Python 2.7.5/3.4, twine version 1.9.1 (pkginfo: 1.4.1, requests: 2.8.1, setuptools: 28.8.0,
requests-toolbelt: 0.8.0, tqdm: 4.19.5)

I am an absolute beginner to Python and Nexus :)

Hosting several PyPI repositories as shown below:

[image]

Let's consider the repos. **python-packaging**

[image]

1.**register** fails

```
[root@l4496t dist]# twine register --repository-url http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/ python-packaging-2.0.tar.gz
Registering package to http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/
Enter your username: devjenkinsuser
Enter your password:
Registering python-packaging-2.0.tar.gz
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException for url: http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/
```

nexus.log:

```
2018-02-12 13:40:00,002+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2018-02-12 13:40:00,003+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2018-02-12 13:40:36,766+0000 WARN  [qtp153196240-253]  devjenkinsuser org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet - Failure servicing: POST /repository/python-packaging/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.pypi.internal.HostedHandlers.extractPayloads(HostedHandlers.java:141)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.pypi.internal.HostedHandlers.lambda$2(HostedHandlers.java:106)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.UnitOfWorkHandler.handle(UnitOfWorkHandler.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ContentHeadersHandler.handle(ContentHeadersHandler.java:44)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ConditionalRequestHandler.handle(ConditionalRequestHandler.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.assetdownloadcount.internal.AssetDownloadCountContributedHandler.handle(AssetDownloadCountContributedHandler.java:53)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.HandlerContributor.handle(HandlerContributor.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:44)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:52)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context$proceed$5.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.pypi.internal.PyPiRecipeSupport$_closure1.doCall(PyPiRecipeSupport.groovy:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor437.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.TimingHandler.handle(TimingHandler.java:46)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.start(Context.java:114)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Router.dispatch(Router.java:63)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.ConfigurableViewFacet.dispatch(ConfigurableViewFacet.java:52)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.ConfigurableViewFacet.dispatch(ConfigurableViewFacet.java:43)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.dispatchAndSend(ViewServlet.java:200)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.doService(ViewServlet.java:162)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.service(ViewServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicServletPipeline.service(DynamicServletPipeline.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.executeChain(SecurityFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ExhaustRequestFilter.doFilter(ExhaustRequestFilter.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.licensing.internal.LicensingRedirectFilter.doFilter(LicensingRedirectFilter.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.EnvironmentFilter.doFilter(EnvironmentFilter.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.HeaderPatternFilter.doFilter(HeaderPatternFilter.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicFilterPipeline.dispatch(DynamicFilterPipeline.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.DelegatingFilter.doFilter(DelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

2.**upload** succeeds(though nothing in nexus.log for the same)

3.**pip search** fails with an NPE

```
[root@l4496t dist]# pip search -i http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/ python-packaging -vvv
Starting new HTTP connection (1): proxysesosrv.com
"POST http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/ HTTP/1.1" 401 0
User for l5111t.sss.se.com:8081: devjenkinsuser
Password:
"POST http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1998
HTTP error 500 while getting http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 45, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 62, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1105, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1445, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 776, in request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 862, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException for url: http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/
```

nexus.log

```
2018-02-12 13:50:00,003+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2018-02-12 13:50:00,004+0000 INFO  [quartz-3-thread-19]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2018-02-12 13:51:05,429+0000 WARN  [qtp153196240-220]  devjenkinsuser org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet - Failure servicing: POST /repository/python-packaging/
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.pypi.internal.HostedHandlers.extractPayloads(HostedHandlers.java:126)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.pypi.internal.HostedHandlers.lambda$2(HostedHandlers.java:106)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.UnitOfWorkHandler.handle(UnitOfWorkHandler.java:39)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ContentHeadersHandler.handle(ContentHeadersHandler.java:44)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ConditionalRequestHandler.handle(ConditionalRequestHandler.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.assetdownloadcount.internal.AssetDownloadCountContributedHandler.handle(AssetDownloadCountContributedHandler.java:53)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.HandlerContributor.handle(HandlerContributor.java:67)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ExceptionHandler.handle(ExceptionHandler.java:44)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:52)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context$proceed$5.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.pypi.internal.PyPiRecipeSupport$_closure1.doCall(PyPiRecipeSupport.groovy:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor437.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.TimingHandler.handle(TimingHandler.java:46)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.proceed(Context.java:80)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Context.start(Context.java:114)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Router.dispatch(Router.java:63)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.ConfigurableViewFacet.dispatch(ConfigurableViewFacet.java:52)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.ConfigurableViewFacet.dispatch(ConfigurableViewFacet.java:43)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.dispatchAndSend(ViewServlet.java:200)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.doService(ViewServlet.java:162)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.service(ViewServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicServletPipeline.service(DynamicServletPipeline.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.executeChain(SecurityFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ExhaustRequestFilter.doFilter(ExhaustRequestFilter.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.sonatype.nexus.licensing.internal.LicensingRedirectFilter.doFilter(LicensingRedirectFilter.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.EnvironmentFilter.doFilter(EnvironmentFilter.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.HeaderPatternFilter.doFilter(HeaderPatternFilter.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicFilterPipeline.dispatch(DynamicFilterPipeline.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.DelegatingFilter.doFilter(DelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

3.**pip install** fails due to some format issue

```
[root@l4496t dist]# pip install --trusted-host -i http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/ python-packaging -vvv
Collecting http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/
  Starting new HTTP connection (1): proxysesosrv.com
  "GET http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
  Downloading http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/
  Downloading from URL http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/
  Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-1xw4qh1g-unpack/python-packaging.htm (downloaded from /tmp/pip-f0c2_o7z-build, content-type: text/html); cannot detect archive format
Cleaning up...
Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-f0c2_o7z-build
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 663, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 620, in unpack_file
    'Cannot determine archive format of %s' % location
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-f0c2_o7z-build
```

If I use the --allowed-external option, the output changes a bit

```
pip install --trusted-host --allow-external -i http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/ python-packaging -vvv
Collecting python-packaging
  The repository located at l5111t.sss.se.com is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host l5111t.sss.se.com'.
  0 location(s) to search for versions of python-packaging:
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-packaging (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for python-packaging
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for python-packaging
```

Comment: Configure the client tools using these instructions:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools

Comment: Assuming this (https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-16083) is you, please consider answering your question to help others who ran into this.

Comment: @rseddon Yeah, I have now posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the URL specified 'The URL used to access this repository' in the repository's settings shown in the Nexus UI. It was only after I browsed through [this](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools) part of documentation that I realized that one needs to append a 'simple' at the end of the repository URL. The command that worked:

```
pip install --index-url http://l5111t.sss.se.com:8081/repository/python-packaging/simple python-packaging --trusted-host l5111t.sss.se.com -vvv
```